# rails 4 premit for array

Tags: parameters, ruby-2.1, ruby-on-rails-4.1

little bit confuse in permit

HI I am using rails 4.1.1 & ruby 2.1.2

```
Params

"user_experienced_non_it"=>[{"experienced_non_it_reg_id"=>"132", "experience"=>"2years", "remark"=>""}]
```

Controller code:

```
def user_experienced_non_it_params
    params.require(:user_experienced_non_it).permit(:experienced_non_it_reg_id, :user_id,    :experience, :remark)
end
```

but I am getting the following error

undefined method `permit' for Array:

Answer (score 1):

The permit method should be called on a hash so you can change your params to be:

```
params

"user_experienced_non_it"=>{"experienced_non_it_reg_id"=>"132", "experience"=>"2years", "remark"=>""}
```

Or, if you need the value of "user_experienced_non_it" to be an array for some reason you can use:

```
controller

def user_experienced_non_it_params
  params.permit(user_experienced_non_it: [:experienced_non_it_reg_id, :experience, :user_id, :remark])
end
```